# printing the month repeately in mysql query which is not my required result

Tags: php, mysqli

I am generating bar charts getting a data from database, i want to show the doctors registered monthly in charts and i am using datetime format of mysql but i am getting the repeating month. For example i have register one doctor in the month of october and 23 doctors in the month of november. Here is my query which i am trying

```
"select  DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%b') as month, doc_id,docName , count(*) as total from
view_doc_create_date
group by created_date order by month DESC;"
```

I am getting the output like that

```
+-------+--------+---------------+-------+
| month | doc_id | docName       | total |
+-------+--------+---------------+-------+
| Oct   |     13 | Shahid Khan   |     1 |
| Nov   |      4 | Amina Maqsood |     7 |
| Nov   |      6 | Abdul Moeed   |     6 |
| Nov   |      7 | Faiza Khan    |    10 |
+-------+--------+---------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by month

```
"select  DATE_FORMAT(created_date,'%b') as month, doc_id,docName , count(*) as total from
view_doc_create_date
group by month order by month DESC;"
```

Comment: Great! please set the question to answered.